# My filter submission function isn't working as intended. Uncaught TypeError: country.match is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

My code isn't working specifically with the country.name.match function not working as intended.

Error code is as follows:
App.js:27 Uncaught TypeError: country.name.match is not a function

REST API being used:
https://restcountries.com/#api-endpoints-v3-all

Rest of the code if needed:https://github.com/jnatividad-design/FSO/tree/main/part2/countries

```js
const handleFilterSubmit = (event) => {
      console.log(event.target.value)
      setNewFilter(event.target.value)
      const regex = new RegExp ( newFilter, 'i');
      const filteredCountries = () => countries.filter(country => country.name.match(regex));
      setCountries(filteredCountries)
    }
```

Comment: Maybe `country.name` is not a string?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what was wrong. The REST API changed the database's structure slightly, adding more specificity to the country and its name. Originally it went `country.name` instead, it must be `country.name.common` as the name is another object with properties such as common name, official name, etc.

```js
const handleFilterSubmit = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.value)
    setNewFilter(event.target.value)
    const regex = new RegExp ( newFilter, 'i');
    const filteredCountries = () => countries.filter(country => country.name.common.match(regex));
    setCountries(filteredCountries)
}
```